# Write the particular equation expressing cost in terms of miles traveled

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To take a taxi in downtown St. Louis, it will cost you $3.00$ to go a mile. After $6$ miles, it will cost $5.25$. The cost varies linearly with the distance traveled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you travel $n$ miles.  If $n = 1$, then your total cost is:

$$3.00$$

Once you have traveled more than $6$ miles, $n-6$ miles will be at the rate of $5.25$/mile, and $6$ will be at $3.00$/miles.

So, your equation is:

$$(n-6) \cdot 5.25 + 6 \cdot 3 = \text{cost if }n > 6 $$

$$n \cdot 3 = \text{ cost if }n < 6$$

Comment: I don't know how to delete that italic writing. Sorry..